# error message when implementing `((->) r)` monad (type mismatch)

Tags: function, haskell, monads

I'm just starting to learn haskell, and I'm trying to implement some common monads as exercises for myself. As I was fiddling with the `((->) r)` monad, I implemented this (wrong) definition:

```hs
instance Monad ((->) r) where
   return x = \_ -> x
   m >>= f = \c -> (f . m) c
```

GHCi complained to me with

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘t -> b’
  `b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      (>>=) :: forall a b. (t -> a) -> (a -> t -> b) -> t -> b
```

whereas the type should be:

```hs
(>>=) :: (t -> a ) -> (a -> t -> b) -> t -> b
```

Why does my implementation break it? And seemingly, the `forall` version should give the exact same type, but GHCi thinks otherwise. What's the difference?

Comment: Where do you see existential quantification?

Comment: @melpomene sorry if I'm using the wrong term. I didn't use existential quantification in my definitions, but GHC thinks the type signature includes a `forall a b.`

Comment: Hint: In `m >>= \x -> f x`, `m` needs an `r`, but so does `f x`.

Comment: Why does your `>>=` have a non-standard type? Did you define your own `>>=` with the arguments flipped?

Comment: @melpomene yea, i'm trying to implement `>>=` myself to see if i really understand monads. with my definition, that's where the `forall` comes in.

Comment: `forall` is irrelevant. The error message shows explicit declarations for all type variables, but `(>>=) :: (a -> t -> b) -> (t -> a) -> t -> b` means exactly the same thing. The real problem is that the type should be `(>>=) :: (t -> a) -> (a -> t -> b) -> t -> b` (that is, `(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` with `m = ((->) t)`). Why isn't it?

Comment: I got it now, thanks guys! I feel like I've leveled up in understanding. both in trying to reason with type and understanding error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fatal misunderstanding was that I thought the error message meant that my implementation had an incorrect type signature. (I thought that because there was a `forall` in the type signature.) It turns out that's not the actual error, and my error in the implementation was that I needed to apply another `r` term to both `f` and `m` in my implementation. Thanks to @luqui and @melpomene for pointing it out to me

Comment: Could you accept this answer so it no longer shows up as 'unanswered'?

Comment: @bradrn I'm not allowed to until after 2 days, I'll do it then

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I'd better be a bit more careful when I add these sort of comments then.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really worth a self-answer. The correct instance for `Monad ((->) r)` is widely available.

Comment: @chepner yea, i guess the main learning for me was how to read the error message. Maybe the question can be edited to reflect that, or even deleted? what do you think?